# Something is wrong with `\setmathdigitfont` of XePersian

Tags: xetex, math-fonts, xepersian

From 2014 until 2020 I have used of a `tex` template that is working not so bad and was error-free. But after installing `TeXlive 2021` it is rapidly produce error after calling `\setmathdigitfont{Font name}`.

```
Package fontspec Warning: Font "Fontname" does not contain requested Script (fontspec) "Persian".


! Package xepersian-mathsdigitspec Error: The font "Fontname" does not
(xepersian-mathsdigitspec) contain U+066A.
```

I have not changed anything of template. It also produce error for all fonts I have checked ever even in the following simple MWE. **It is really annoying**. All my friends are emailing me frequently that something is wrong here.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}


\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{B Nazanin}%--> this is OK
\setmathdigitfont{Yas}%--> this produce error for these Persian fonts: Yas, B Yas, XB Niloofar, PGaramond etc.

\author{فردوسی}
\title{شاهنامه}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    این یک آز مایش است
    و یک فرمول ریاضی به صورت زیر
    \[\sqrt{\dfrac{5}{20x_{2}}} \]
\end{document}
```

I am using `TeXlive 2021` and `Xepersian` package and compiling with `XeLaTeX`.

Comment: please show the error that you get (the exact error copied from the log file)

Comment: David. I added the error of one of my friends TeX. This is for mine: `! Undefined control sequence.
\__xepersian_mathsdigitspec_primitive_font_char_if_exist:nF ...
   \l_fontspec_font "#1\scan_...
l.11 
     
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.`

Comment: yes I just downloaded the font and saw.

Comment: @C.F.G I can't test this right now, but adding `\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \etex_iffontchar:D \tex_iffontchar:D
\ExplSyntaxOff` might help.

Comment: tnx @MarcelKrüger .But it is a temporary solution and I want to know why that command produce error?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger yep that fixes it, C.F.G add Marcel's line before loading xpersian

Comment: @C.F.G it is a change in expl3 (the primitives now have `\tex_` prefix not `\etex_` but it was some years ago. (this already failed in texlive 2020)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but that was fine in my previous texlive 2020

Comment: can you open an issue at https://github.com/persiantex/xepersian/issues

Comment: @DavidCarlisle there is already an issue https://github.com/persiantex/xepersian/issues/20

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and another one https://github.com/persiantex/xepersian/issues/17

Comment: The TeX.SE is more active in google results rather than GitHub. so posting here is much helpful for other users.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yep and a pull request with the fix

Comment: @C.F.G yes/no. the author isn't active here so to get the code actually fixed at source you need to contact the author, but as there is already an issue raised there that's done, no need to add another one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that `xepersian` uses the command `\etex_iffontchar:D` which has been deprecated since 2018 and removed in current versions. The functionality is still available under the name `\tex_iffontchar:D`, so you can fix the issue by recreating `\etex_iffontchar:D` as an alias for `\tex_iffontchar:D`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_set_eq:NN \etex_iffontchar:D \tex_iffontchar:D
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{B Nazanin}%--> this is OK
\setmathdigitfont{Yas}%--> this produce error for these Persian fonts: Yas, B Yas, XB Niloofar, PGaramond etc.

\author{فردوسی}
\title{شاهنامه}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    این یک آز مایش است
    و یک فرمول ریاضی به صورت زیر
    \[\sqrt{\dfrac{5}{20x_{2}}} \]
\end{document}
```