# Installation texlive 2018

Tags: xepersian, texlive-2018

I need texlive 2017 and texlive 2018 for running my thesis file; because xepersian package dose not work by texlive 2021. Which site I can use to downloading it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should be able to get xepersian running in texlive 2021 with possibly minor fixes eg https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603700/something-is-wrong-with-setmathdigitfont-of-xepersian/603701#603701

Comment: see also https://gist.github.com/majid-vaghari/3986f3643d5fbe5b4e10b954f1ab9115  which is linked from the issue at the xepersian github source repositary.

Comment: If you really wish to go the "downdating-route":  [https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html) has a section "Past releases".  Following that, you get, e.g., the following link: [https://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/](https://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/). For each release, there also is a large .iso-file ...